# Python script to open a file or program

Tags: python, file, passwords

I am trying to make a simple python program which when run, it will ask a password and if the password is correct, it will open a certain file with a program (or open a program itself). Maybe not the password part but only how to open a file with a program or a program itself. Thanks in advance. ^_^

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open any program in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48483765/how-to-open-any-program-in-python)

Comment: No, it did not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Above I have linked a library that does just this. It allows you to pass in arguments to run an external command.

Simply import it at the top of your program: import subprocess

Read the documentation linked to find the method that you would like to use to solve your problem (subprocess.call())